# I want to launch the adonisjs environment with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

https://github.com/SebastianPuchet/docker-adonis

I'm trying to build docker, but it doesn't work

When I docker-compose up -d

I get an error

error--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR:
Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
parent. Are you in the right directory?

```
    Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

---

ERROR: Service 'adonis-api' failed to build : COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat package.json: file does not exist

Answer (score 0):

The COPY command in the docker file is trying to copy package.json to the image but there is no such file in the repository.
From a quick look at the repo, I would guess that it expects you take these docker files and use them in your on js project.

Comment: Does that mean it doesn't create a development environment for AdonisJs?

Comment: No it does not. It expects your application to be ready it go and then tries to package it